# About TCO SRM 277 Div 1, 1000 - SafeJourney

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to solve Topcoder SRM 277 Div 1 Level 3 problem("SafeJourney").

But I don't understand why test case 02 should return 0.

I drew a picture which demonstrates test case 02.

[image: TC 02]

I thought the solution would be 1 but that is not the correct answer.

Why answer is 0?

**Edit : I also thought moving on the city boundary is not reasonable.
         So, I thought the solution would be 1. I can't understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I read the problem description again. Finally it makes sense.